# New relic iOS framework, header not found

Tags: ios, xcode, newrelic

I am using New Relic in my iOS app. In my original xcode-project things work as expected. When I check out the project from Git on another computer (or the same computer at another location), I am unable to find NewRelic.h. I get the following error when I try to build:

```
'NewRelicAgent/NewRelic.h' file not found
```

The framework is added to Git, and I use several other third party frameworks that work without problem. If I remove the New Relic import the rest of the project work as expected. In the non-functioning version that I check out, I have even tried to remove New Relic and re-add the framework, but this produces the same error.

I have searched the project for any absolute search paths, but it seems like there are none. I would like some advice on how to make xcode find the file.

Comment: i'm actually experiencing the same issue. were you able to resolve this?

Comment: I think I solved it in a kind of hack-ish manner where I added the actual header files to the project. Not pretty, but then again, finding a pretty solution to an ugly problem is hard.

Comment: @Reason, I know its a 3 year old question but i'm facing the same problem right now. Whenever I commit-pushed new relic framework on HG, other developer who take pull of code is unable to see the headers in xcode project, however headers exists under framework in project containing folder in finder. Please let me know how to get rid of it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This actually looks like a problem with xcode. A few users found a very simple fix that's outlined here: [Why are static library headers not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095452/why-are-static-library-headers-not-found)

Should be as simple as renaming the folder that contains the .xcodeproject.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error when following their install instructions and imported the framework in the precompiled header. When importing it in the app delegate (which they explicitly state you should NOT do with the new version) everything works. Might be something with XCode6.1. Don't know.